# Using Xamarin, how do I store data on a .csv file to local android storage?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

For example, if I have data in two arrays, ArrayX and ArrayY, how do I write the data into a .csv file in local android storage?

Comment: Full docs and example: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/files/

Comment: Also https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/app-fundamentals/file-system

Answer (score 2):

this assumes ArrayX & ArrayY are non-null and have the same number of elements

```
string path = Path.Combine(System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal), "myfile.csv");

using (StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(path))
{
    for (int ndx = 0; ndx <= ArrayX.Length; ndx++)
    {
      sw.WriteLine(ArrayX[ndx] + "," + ArrayY[ndx]);
    }
}
```